# Sign transaction by user

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm newbie in Ethereum and actually, I'm trying to implement test application which is using smart contracts. On UI I'm using web3.js

Currently, I'm looking for, how user can sign transaction (password, private key, something else). The transaction makes some data manipulation in Smart Contract.

Could you please suggest me best practice for this?

I know, that one of the most popular approach is Metamask, but for me it doesn't good approach. Because, it works only in one browser and with pre-installed plugin. I want to have something what will work for all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to sign transactions on the client side without using plugins. This approach is used by light or web wallets. I'd recommend using a trusted library like [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) from the ConsenSys. You can sign your transactions with the following method:

```
signing.signTx(keystore, pwDerivedKey, rawTx, signingAddress, hdPathString)
```